# Error trying to translate raster image from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:3068 with GDAL with subwindow

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, proj, gdal-translate

I'm new with this GIS stuff and starting work with GDAL.

I'm using this TMS dataset and trying to project to a specific subwindow like this:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <!--
    <UserAgent>Please add a specific user agent text, to avoid the default one being used, and potentially blocked by OSM servers in case a too big usage of it would be seen</UserAgent>
    -->
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

.\gdal_translate.exe -outsize 1416 657 -projwin_srs EPSG:3857 -projwin -44541776.787102 20037508.342787 44541776.787096 -20037508.342781 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml out_openstreetmap_3857.png

since the CRS from dataset is EPSG:3857, we are getting this output:

[image]

but when I try to translate to EPSG:3068 given the relative coordinates to this CRS:

.\gdal_translate.exe -outsize 1416 657 -projwin_srs EPSG:3068 -projwin -24171563.458517 4411319.891314 21223276.268552 -16013557.428654 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml out_openstreetmap_3068.png

I'm facing this error:

ERROR 1: PROJ: push: Invalid latitude
ERROR 1: Invalid coordinate
ERROR 1: -projwin_srs ignored since coordinate transformation failed.

I believe that is occurring because EPSG:3068 don't covers the entire globe, so how can I get the maximum extent for EPSG:3068 in this case? What I'm missing here?

EDIT:
Based on @user30184 comments,I tried use GDALWarp like this:

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3068 -te -24171563.458517 4411319.891314 21223276.268552 -16013557.428654 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml out_openstreetmap_3068.png

But I'm receiving the following error:

ERROR 1: PROJ: cart: Invalid latitude
ERROR 1: PROJ: webmerc: Invalid latitude

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 2:

Based on @user30184 last comment, I got good results doing something like this:

.\gdalwarp.exe -ts 1416 657 -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3068 -te -1587340.079127 -562496.970000 1187701.599127 335080.070000 -te_srs EPSG:3068 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml out_openstreetmap_3068.jpg

I got these coordinates from projected bounds described here: https://epsg.io/3068

But, How do I got this values programmatically?
I tried use 'proj_get_area_of_use' from proj lib, but I'm receiving the values as degrees.

Also tried use 'proj_trans_bounds', but the values are different from that ones in EPSG site and didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Error messages should always be placed in the Question body as text. Images are not legible on all devices, and can't be searched by others with the same problem. Please[Edit] the Question.

Comment: @Vince It's done, thanks.

Comment: Gdal_translate does not re-project data if that is your aim. Use gdalwarp instead. Projwin_srs is used for telling in which coordinate system the coordinates of the projwin are. Now your projwin is outside the valid area of EPSG:3068 https://epsg.io/3068 but anyway, the biggest mistake is to use a wrong tool.

Comment: @user30184 Take a look on my last edition, I tried with GDALWarp but it still not working, am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that `-te -24171563.458517 4411319.891314 21223276.268552 -16013557.428654` is given in the units of EPSG:3068. For me the coordinates look like EPSG:3857 ones. If that is true you must read the documentation from here https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te_srs and add `-te_srs epsg:3857`.

Comment: @user30184 I think I got it. I tested using the projectd bounds that I got from https://epsg.io/3068 and seems working, but I don't know how to get this values programmatically. Take a look on my last edit to more details. Thanks.